# How to filter an IPv6 traffic from Google Analytics data?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, ipv6

I need to filter my local IP address out of my Google Analytics data.

I'm following this tutorial on how to do it:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en

If your network is IPv6 compatible and you are sending Analytics IPv6 addresses, then you cannot filter IPv4 addresses.

Apparently, my network does that, so I need to filter IPv6 addresses.

Here are the instructions on how to do it.

[image]

They explicitly say that you should enter the IP minus the subnet part, which apparently, from the example is the last part after the last colon: cf19

So the IP entered was `2620:0:10e2:2:c4bc:9fd2:974f`, leaving out the cf19

**QUESTION**

These are the IPv6 addresses in my local network:

```
Desktop PC: XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXX:AAAA:AAAA:AAAA:AAAA
Laptop:     XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXX:BBBB:BBBB:BBBB:BBBB
Mobile:     XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXX:CCCC:CCCC:CCCC:CCCC
```

They all share the same `XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXX` part, but each one has different numbers for the rest of the pattern.

Should I make my filter like this?

Filter traffic from IP address that begins with: `XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXX` ?

I'm confused because that common pattern looks way different than what the documentation suggests. The doc example shows that I would have to remove just the last 4 digits, but that wouldn't make sense on my case, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as you have suggested:

> Filter traffic from IP address that begins with: XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXX

Just make sure to follow the golden rule and setup a test view and test it first before applying it to main reporting view.

Comment: Thanks. How can I set up a test view? Once I've filtered, there's no turning back? I thought I could just erase the filter and get the data back. How does it work?

Comment: Filtered data is non recoverable. 
Create a new View and name it Test (so you are sure which view it is).
Wait a couple of hours, because real time reporting can take up to 2hrs to sync with GA config changes such as filters being applied. Then browse the site and make sure you cant see your site activity in the real time reporting in the Test view. Once you know it works, then you can apply it to any of your main reporting views that you want to exclude your site activity from.

Comment: Thank you for this advice!